# How to record audio from the Bluetooth earphones mic in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-bluetooth

My Bluetooth earphones can be used to make phone calls but I'm not able to access the mic in android studio with kotlin.

I have tried different audio sources and If it doesn't crash right away it defaults to the DEFAULT mic.

```
package com.plcoding.audiorecorder.record

import android.content.Context
import android.media.MediaRecorder
import android.os.Build
import android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream

class AndroidAudioRecorder(
    private val context: Context
): AudioRecorder {

    private var recorder: MediaRecorder? = null

    private fun createRecorder(): MediaRecorder {
        return if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            MediaRecorder(context)
        } else MediaRecorder()
    }

    override fun start(outputFile: File) {
        createRecorder().apply {
            setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.UNPROCESSED)
            setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
            setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC)
            setOutputFile(FileOutputStream(outputFile).fd)

            prepare()
            start()

            recorder = this
        }
    }

    override fun stop() {
        recorder?.stop()
        recorder?.reset()
        recorder = null
    }
}
```